# Definition of slack variable in time window routing

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

time window constraint are defined by

`time_dimension.CumulVar(node).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])`

and the time dimension by

`routing.AddDimension(evaluator, slack_max, capacity, fix_start_cumul_to_zero, name)`

What is the relationship between the allowed values of `CumulVar(node)` and `slack_max`? For example, say that the time window is `(50,60)` and slack is `5`. Does that mean that a value of the cumul var of `45` is also admissible, or does the slack relate to values inside the range? Does `max_slack=0` mean that the value of the cumul var must be either `50` or `60`, in the example above?

Is there a paper or detailed page about the mathematical model that is used my the routing model of or-tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For time window constraint, you can see the slack value as waiting time.
From the source code.

> // if j == next(i),
>   // cumuls(j) = cumuls(i) + transits(i) + slacks(i)

src: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/d44fb1b423f9d6658c142c041143a4f54b5106d3/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L1356-L1357

e.g. Supposing your are at node A at time 0 aka `A(0)` and you have `B([40,60])` and transit time is `T(50)`. Thus you have:
`B(40) < A(0) + T(50)` -> means too late to reach the lower bound even with no waiting time.
`B(60) = A(0) + T(50) + 10` -> means vehicle can wait at node A up to 10min and still be in time at node B.

Second example: `A(0)`, `B([40,60])`, `T(30)`:
`B(40) = A(0) + T(30) + 10` -> have to wait 10min
`B(60) = A(0) + T(30) + 30` -> have to wait 30min
if slack max is `5` this route is forbidden because otherwise vehicle will be at most at node B at `35 = A(0) + T(30) + 5` which is too early
i.e. not in the range `[40,60]` so for the solver the time windows constraint can't be respected...
note: we can also deduce:
`B(40) = A(5) + T(30) + 5`
`B(60) = A(30) + T(30)`
So vehicle must be at node A in range `[5,30]` to be **on time** at node B with `slack_max = 5`.
i.e. With slack max you can limit the maximum waiting time (extra capacity) allowed along the route.

Routing use a "two steps" algorithms.
1) Try to find a first solution an can use various algorithm
cf. https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_options#first-solution-strategy-options for paper reference
2) Can use a local search to optimize this first solution
again several methods are implemented cf https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_options#local-search-options